# How to align a logo within a red background with equal padding on all sides

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sass, flexbox

Given the following code I got
[image]

What I need is the red background have the same padding around th logo, now it has excessive left portion, the desire outcome for red background is

[image]

how do I achieve that

html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navigationContainer fixedHeader">
        <div class="leftContainer">
            <a href='/' class="logoContainer">
               hello
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="middleContainer">
            <div class="customSelectContainer">
                <select id="lang" placeholder="def">
                    <!-- Options will be added by JS -->
                </select>
            </div>
            <button class="generateButton" onclick="handleGenerateButtonClick()">Auto Generate</button>
        </div>
        <div class="rightContainer">
            <div class="userProfileWrapper" onmouseenter="handleMouseEnter()">
                <div class="userInitials">th</div>
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <div class="content">
                        <div class="list">
                            <p onclick="handleSignOut()" class="title">Sign Out</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

`styles.css` code:

```
.navigationContainer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 56px;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 0 rgba(57, 71, 81, 0.16);
  flex: 0 0 300px;
  column-gap: 24px;
}

.fixedHeader {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 999;
}

.leftContainer {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 0 16px;
}

.logoContainer {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.middleContainer {
  display: flex;
  gap: 24px;
  align-items: center;
}

.customSelectContainer {
  margin-top: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

.rightContainer {
  flex: 1;
}

.userProfileWrapper {
  margin-right: 8px;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  transition: 0.3s;
  background: red;
  padding: 8px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.userProfileWrapper:hover {
  background: rgba(43, 69, 87, 0.08);
}

.userProfileWrapper:hover .dropdown {
  max-height: 1000px;
  overflow: visible !important;
}

.dropdown {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: overflow 0s 0.3s, all 0.3s;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 372px;
  transform: translate(0, 100%);
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 8px 16px rgba(57, 71, 81, 0.16));
}

.content {
  padding: 4px 0;
  background: #fff;
}

.userInitials {
  background-color: #D9EDFF;
  margin-left: auto;
  font: 14px/20px 'NotoSansBold', sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  white-space: nowrap;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.list {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.list.disabled {
  opacity: 0.5;
  cursor: no-drop;
  user-select: none;
}

.list .title {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 8px 16px;
}
```

Comment: You could remove `.rightContainer {flex: 1;}`. It's telling that box to grow as wide as it can, but you don't want that.

Comment: @ralph.m that is needed to make the dropdown list with autogenerate button center align (that's why setting left and right container with flex:1)

Comment: Okay, try this then: `.userProfileWrapper {width: max-content; margin-left: auto;}`. That seems to work for me.

Comment: @ralph.m looks like it works! but how the `width: max-content` helps here?

Comment: `width: max-content` tells the element just to be as wide as the content inside it. It's very handy. Could also use `min-content`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
.rightContainer {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.userProfileWrapper {
  margin-right: 8px;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  transition: 0.3s;
  background: red;
  padding: 8px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could give the header a display of grid, give the header a fixed height, and  give the logo container a width which is the same of the height of the header. Now you can give the logo container a box-sizing of border-box so that you can set a padding on the inside. Then you can give the circle a width and height of 100% and a border radius of 50%.

```css
:root {
 --header-height: 5em;
}

header {
 height: 5em;
 width: 100%;
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: 1fr var(--header-height);
}

.logo-conainer {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 padding: .5em;
}

.circle {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, but could we maintain the flex layout (assume can't change) and change only the css of userProfileWrapper, or add any addition div between rightcontent and userprofilewrapper to solve the issue?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to do this with flexbox, but why would you want to use flexbox? grid seems like the best way to achieve your goal to me.